# Getting a False return from listview

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-framelayout

I am getting a false return when implementing a listview within a framelayout/tab layout. For the life of me I can't seem to figure out why I am getting a false return on my app when implementing a listview. The code works on a external project but I cant seem to intergrate it into this one. I will list the main activity groups used within the project and the xml file for the page that the string is meant to appear on. Sorry its alot of code but this has been driving me insane over the last few days cause it should be relatively simple.

The xml layout files are held in framelayout coding within the main.xml(which is not shown) so have I got the ID wrong when referencing? Any help to solve this problem would be amazing as I know its a really simple solution that Im just missing. Thanks guys.

If I havnt explained it well a picturee of the error is below
View the page here http://i41.tinypic.com/do04ee.png

Their are no log errors.

Main Activity
 **(Please note I have removed code to make it more relavant and clear and to show the links from activity to activity)**

```
package workout.fitty;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class WorkoutFittyActivity extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

 // More

    **intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MoreActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("More",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_more))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);**

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
}
}
```

**MoreActivity**

```
package workout.fitty;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MoreActivity extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.more_layout);
    Intent Intent = new Intent(this, MyListActivity.class);
}
}
```

**MyListActivity**

```
package workout.fitty;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    String[] values = new String[] { "BMI", "Body Measurements", "Logs",
            "Feedback", "How To Use", "About" };
    // Use your own layout
    **ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.more_layout, R.id.label, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);**
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

**And the XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="22px"
    android:layout_height="22px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:layout_marginTop="4px"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="20px" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Main XML File with container and framelayout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

        <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in the `MoreActivity` activity? In the `onCreate()` of the `MoreActivity` activity` you have created an `Intent` but you didn't actually start another activity with a call to `startActivity(Intent)` or `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`(or you just remove this part)?

Comment: Hi Slukian Thanks so much. I dont know what I was trying to do with the MoreActivity.  I didnt even notice I didnt need it. Its the simple things you always miss ha! Its sorted now and the list is working. I just needed to remove MoreActivity. Thanks alot. I feel like a idiot not noticing something like that.

Answer (score 0):

change your:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.more_layout, R.id.label, values);
```

in

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
       R.layout.more_layout, values);
```